# How to restart a daemon program with another argument using systemd watchdog

Tags: linux, systemd

An application managed by systemd should be restarted when it freezes. Systemd should restart application passing another argument as on the first time after boot. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I take it you made a systemd service that runs an application that often freezes.

I recommend you have a look at this answer to detect when your application freezes, unless you've programmed this application yourself, in which case you should handle the error properly or have the application exit.

[Can systemd detect and kill hung processes?](https://superuser.com/questions/689017/can-systemd-detect-and-kill-hung-processes)

With that, you can have systemd call the application with another argument, as described here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441575/proper-way-to-use-onfailure-in-systemd

If you didn't write the service file and/or application, you'll most likely find the service file under `/lib/systemd/system/<appname>.service` and the method of detecting and handling freezes would be the same.